# SQL - How to replace partial text in a text field that contains matching data from list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about replace function (or anything similar to that).

I have a query that returns more than 1500 results and one of the columns is a 'BODY' column which includes inside sql query.

The columns of the returned table are: **Id**,**name**, **date**, **title**, **body**.
In the **body** column i have sql query such as:

```
"select * from tbl.student s inner join tbl.teacher t on s.id = t.sId 

where title like '%Joni%'"
```

And than I have a separate list of 60 tables which some of them for example: **tbl.student**, **tbl.teacher**, **tbl.class**, **tbl.school** and etc.

I want to run on all 1500 results that iv'e got, look for each result if **body** field contains one of the tables that in the list (**tbl.student**, **tbl.teacher**, **tbl.class**, **tbl.school** ...
) and if so i want to replace **tbl.** to **abc.**

For example, if one of the results contains in its body field **tbl.student** I want to replace it to **abc.student**

What will be the most effective way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Side note, that smells like a terrible design. For your question, `update ... field = replace.... where body like '%tbl.student%'`

Comment: Double tagging `mysql` and `sql server` isn't recommended.  As these are different products they often require different solutions.  Agree with @JorgeCampos; storing sql in a field is problematic.  As your schema changes you'll continually need to revisit the stored sql.  [MySql Replace Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).  [SQL Server Replace function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql).

Comment: I agree that storing sql in a field is problematic, but it's a given situation that i have to deal with. Is there any practical solution to my problem?